# open source news reader framework for iphone ipad?

Tags: objective-c

is there any objective c frameworks/code base that help you to develop a rss news reader app instantly?

I have only found TapLynx but it is closed source and not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google showed up [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser). There are also numerous tutorials to build RSS readers that include source code, such as [this one](http://www.websector.de/blog/2009/02/08/simple-rss-reader-for-iphone-using-puremvc-standard-for-objective-c/) or [this one](http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/).